# Invariant on "Find K Closest Elements" problem

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, binary-search, loop-invariants

I run across this problem:

Given a sorted array, two integers `k` and `x`, find the `k` closest elements to `x` in the array. The result should also be sorted in ascending order. If there is a tie, the smaller elements are always preferred.

For example, given `[1,2,3,4,5]`, `k=4`, `x=3`, we should have `[1,2,3,4]`. There is one solution using binary search:

```
    vector<int> findClosestElements(vector<int>& arr, int k, int x) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = arr.size() - k;
    while (left < right)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (x - arr[mid] <= arr[mid+k] - x)
        {
            right = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return vector<int>(arr.begin() + left, arr.begin() + left + k);
}
```

I couldn't understand `if (x - arr[mid] <= arr[mid+k] - x)` part and I try to explain this using precondition, invariant, and postcondition like we do with the
simple binary search problem. But, I have no clue what's the invariant in this case and how we prove the invariant holds through the loop execution. I also follow the [article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/) from topcoder but that doesn't help.

My attempt for the invariant: the index of the first number that is among the k closest values for the given target is in [left, right]. However, I cannot fully convince myself this is correct and actually holds during the loop.

If this question belongs to stackoverflow, let me know and I'll post it there instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If `x - arr[mid] <= arr[mid+k] - x`, then for any `l` that `l > mid`, we have

```
x - arr[l-1] <= x - a[mid] <= arr[mid+k] - x <= arr[l+k] - x,
arr[l-1] - x <= arr[l+k] - x,
```

which means `|arr[l-1] - x| <= |arr[l+k] - x|`. So for any range `[l, l+k]` where `l > mid`, we can move it to left until `l == mid` while the elements contained are no farther from `x`, therefore it is safe to set `right = mid`.

Otherwise, the proof is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of the algorithm is that `mid` will indicate the starting point of the subarray of length `k` that we are interested in (this a bit more specific than your correct intuition about this being in the interval `[left,right]`).

Notice that `x - arr[mid] <= arr[mid+k] - x` is equivalent to `x <= (arr[mid] + arr[mid+k])/2`, which in particular implies that `x <= arr[mid+k]`. If `x-arr[mid]` were a negative number, it means that clearly we can move to the left, since `x` is definitely not in `[arr[mid],arr[mid + k]]`. So suppose that `x - arr[mid]` is positive, and suppose for a contradiction that shifting the interval by one to the right gives a better solution: by our conditions and the fact that the array is ordered, we have `arr[mid+k+1]-x >= arr[mid+k]-x >= x-arr[mid]`, which proves that `arr[mid+k+1]` is further from `x` than `arr[mid]` is, a contradiction (notice that we are required to give preference to the smaller elements, so even if the inequalities above were in fact equalities, moving to the right would be a mistake).

This proves that is is safe to set `right=mid`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. From your explanation I think my invariant statement is correct. However, if we set `right = mid`, how do we ensure that the interval can cover the starting point of the subarray: the starting point might appear in `[mid, x]`. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, my answer needs some major reworking. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I think your proof still doesn't show `right = mid` is the safe choice to ensure invariant holds even index of `x` falls in the interval `[mid, mid+k]`. From your proof, I can see it is bad move to move `right` even further right but you haven't shown move `right` to `mid` is safe choice. Maybe I misunderstand your statements.

Comment: It follows from what I wrote: what I did was to show that the interval you are looking for cannot start to the right of `mid`, hence you can set `right=mid` (seeing `right` as the current bound on how to the right the starting point can be). After this stage, if the current position of `right` is the actual starting point of the solution, only `left` will be moved to the right, until `left=right` and the algorithm terminates.